# Finding the best location for a second legend box

Tags: matplotlib

Space is a premium for a set of subplots that I am automating in which there is sometimes many curves in one subplot. I want to split the legend into two boxes and then optimize the location of the second legend box (the location of the first is provided with loc='best').

Here is am simple example that demonstrates what I am attempting -

```
lines = []
leg = ['test','test1','test2']

lines.append(plot(np.array([1,20]), label = 'test')[0])
lines.append(plot(np.array([1,20]), label = 'test1')[0])
lines.append(plot(np.array([1,20]), label = 'test2')[0])
pltleg1 = plt.legend(lines[:2],leg[:2],loc='best')

# QUESTION: Here I want to put the second legend in the 2nd best location
# or if I could get the location decided upon for pltleg1, I can just add it
# the opposite corner.
pltleg2 = plt.legend(lines[2:],leg[2:],loc='best') 

gca().add_artist(pltleg1)
```

So, I am hoping to find the second best location or if I could retrieve the chosen legend location than it would be okay to choose an alternative. For the second case, it is okay if there is curve overlap. How can this be done?

Comment: if can be useful, `pltleg1.get_bbox_to_anchor()` `Docstring:  return the bbox that the legend will be anchored`. You should then be able to use this info using the `bbox_to_anchor` as shown [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-location)

Comment: can you please be consistent with the use of `plt.`? I suggest you to add it before `plot` and `gca`